# node fstream broken filenames

Tags: node.js, fstream

Currently I'm dealing with the problem, that my nodeJs Scripts - using fstream - break on differnt files.

The filenames seam to contain "bad encoded chars" so LSTAT can't find them.

Is there any known way to filter this files while running the fstream dir reader?

It's no problem if the files are not proccessed if all other files in the dirs work.

```
fstream.Reader(
  { path: dir }
).pipe(zlib.createGzip());
```

The broken filenames look like **A preview for W?mer.jpg** where the **?** represents the broken char.
This leads to an lstat ENOENT

Comment: please post your code and example filenames

Comment: var stream = fstream.Reader({
  path: dir
}).pipe(zlib.createGzip());  


The are some files like "a preview for W?rster" where the ? is the place where the broken char is found.